# C++ - memcpy gives Exception: std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
std::vector<std::byte> size;
static const int header_size_in_bytes = 4;
size.resize(header_size_in_bytes);

size_t body_size{0};
assert(size.size() <= sizeof(body_size));
std::memcpy(&body_size, &size[0], sizeof (body_size));
std::cout << "SIZE: " << body_size << std::endl;
```

I use this piece of code to read the body message size sent over TCP via Boost ASIO.
If I run it single time everything works just fine and I receive output of like

```
SIZE: 5012
```

However If I sent the same message several times quickly in a row I get this :

```
SIZE: 139663746536340
Exception: std::bad_alloc
```

`body_size` becomes incorrect and I get `Exception: std::bad_alloc`. Why is that ?

Where is my mistake and how can I fix it ?

Comment: The assert should be `==`, not `<=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you

```
assert(size.size() <= sizeof(body_size));
```

If you read `sizeof(body_size)` from `size`, it should be `>=`. That assertion will likely fail, because on a 64-bit system, `sizeof(size_t)` is usually 8, not 4.

Comment: If I remove the assertion I still get the same error.

Comment: The assertion is not the problem. `header_size_in_bytes = 4` is. Try 8.

Comment: It should be 4 as I am sending the size in strictly prefixed 4 bytes.

Comment: Yes, but you are copying 4 bytes into an 8 byte integer, leaving 4 other bytes uninitialized. Alternatively, you could change `size_t body_size` to `uint32_t`.

Comment: Yes changing `size_t` to `uint32_t` solved the issue. Can you please provide me link where I can check more in details about those types and their sizes ?

Comment: Mmh, I don't have anything in particular in mind. This one is the result of a quick google search: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/fixed-width-integers-and-size-t/comment-page-2/

Comment: When dealing with data sent between computers, you should _always_ use data types that are not architecture-dependent.  In fact, you must take it one step further and ensure that you're doing correct translation of integer endianness.  Without this, you are asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You're copying eight bytes from a four-element vector, so half the bits of `size` is whatever happened to be lying around.

You can

Change the type of `size` to `uint32_t`, or
Copy the value to a `uint32_t` and then assign it to `size`, or
Avoid size problems by using bitwise operations:

```
size_t body_size =  size[0]
                 | (size[1] << 8)
                 | (size[2] << 16)
                 | (size[3] << 24);
```

(or the other way around, depending on which order you've stored the number in `size` in.)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are reading 8 bytes (sizeof(body_size) == 8 on a 64 bit architecture) from a 4-byte array.

```
std::vector<std::byte> size;
static const int header_size_in_bytes = 4;
size.resize(header_size_in_bytes);

size_t body_size{0};
std::memcpy(&body_size, &size[0], header_size_in_bytes); // Try this
std::cout << "SIZE: " << body_size << std::endl;
```

But I would like to encourage you to use some serialization library, like `FlatBuffers`. Dealing with raw data and copying bytes in C++ is a great exercise, but requires too many checks and asserts to make it work safe across different platforms, which is usually a case when dealing with networking.

As an example I would like to explicitly say about the following: @mch kindly noted in the comments that this code will not work if the platforms are of different endianness. According to the description of the problem this is not the case (at least for now), but the solution can't be considered cross-platfrom (which it never pretended to be).

Comment: `sizeof(size_t)` is usually `8` on non-Windows 64bit systems and your solution will only copy the first `4` bytes. What should OP do with the other `4` byte?

Comment: Those 4 bytes will be zero. `body_size` is initialized with 0 before data is copied into it. As soon as 'size' is std::uint32_t and `body_size` is std::uint64_t everything will work. But personally I would avoid dealing with number representation directly.

Comment: This will only work for little endian machines, it will override the lsb, but on big endian it will override the msb leaving the lsb 4bytes `0`, which will create a wrong huge number.

Comment: Yes, of course, changing of endianness will ruin everything and I believe not only this code. I noted in my answer that generally it is bad idea to copy bytes directly. But the OP's problem was not connected with endianness, I checked the numbers, the lsb 4 bytes were the same.

Comment: @mch, I updated the answer to make it more explicit about the endianness case. Thanks!